# HTML5 banner implementation - AdBlock

Tags: html, banner, adblock

I have website with banner places. I want to implement animated banner with HTML5, but don't want to be blocked by AdBlock addons. For now I use *.swf format and everything is ok.

Is there any solution to do this with HTML5 or any other method except swf?

Comment: "_don't want to be blocked by AdBlock addon_" Are you 100% sure you will get blocked by AdBlock?

Answer (score 0):

The format of the creative isn't usually the reason that Adblock detects your ads. Adblocks looks for a number of things like the AdSense JavaScript code, strings like 'banner' or 'ads' in the creative file path, and so on.

So you can use any format you like for your ad creative, except Flash is not recommended as many browsers and devices no longer support the Flash plugin.